# open one modal and disable the other on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am stuck in a small but weird problem. I have two modals on my page, I want to load the first modal when the page loads, I have done the code to click a button and open the modal but both the modals come up. It has a effect of opening from left to right, I want to keep that so I had added the class in the jquery code. I just want to load the modal that has the id="ModalLogin". As you can see both the modals load when button is clicked. Below is the snippet. Please help.

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('.modal')
    .prop('class', 'modal fade') // revert to default
    .addClass($(this).data('direction'));
  $('.modal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link href="https://www.topconsumerreviews.com/new-common-code/new-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <style type="text/css">
        

      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">

        <ul class="product-rankings-font" style="list-style: none;padding-left: 18px;padding-bottom: 10px;padding: 10px;">
                  <li>Select2 </li>
                  <!-- <li><a href="#modal" class="btn go">Activate Modal</a></li> -->
                  <li style="text-align: center;padding-top: 5px;"><a class='btn btn-primary btn clos' style="width: 160px;" id="bty" data-direction='left'>bty</a></li>
                  </ul>

      <!---- Forgot Password Popup --->
      <div class="modal fade" id="ModalForgotPassword" role="dialog">
         <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 15%;">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Slider 2</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body">
                  <form>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Option 4</button>                       
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Option 5</button>                       
                     </div>
                  </form>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!---- Forgot Password Popup --->
      <!---- Login Popup --->
      <div class="modal fade" id="ModalLogin" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 15%;">
         <!-- Modal content-->
         <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header" style="font-size: 18px;text-align: center;">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" style="color: black;">Text Sample 1</h4>
        <h4 class="modal-title" style="color: black;">Text Sample 2</h4>
      </div>

       <div class="modal-body" style="font-size: 16px">
        <form action="comparelist.php" method="post">
        <ul id="answers-type1" class="myclass"  style="list-style: none;padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;">
          <li class="module form-check-label" style="background: #668693;" value="Listol" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" id="forgotPassword" data-target="#ModalForgotPassword"><span>Option 1</span></li>
          <li class="module form-check-label" style="background: #668693;"><span><a href="page2.html">Option 2</a></span></li>
          
          
        </ul>
      
      </div>
          
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <!---- Login Popup --->








   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to offer another way to use modals: pure CSS.

here is the reference: [click here](http://www.cutcodedown.com/tutorial/modalDialogs)

The idea is you don't need any js,
each modal will be in a div wrapper with id. like this:

```
<div id="modalWrapper">
```

and then you will have a hyperlink where ever you want

```
<a href="#modalWrapper">
```

and the trick is with CSS -
you initially set the position of the modal as absolute and unseen (left:-999em)
and then with the target selector, you bring the modal to the center:

```
#modalWrapper:target {
left:0;
transition:etc..
}
```

and when you do like this - you will open only the desired modal with the button.

hope this will make some help for you.
my first answer on SO

Comment: This is not answer to my question. I cannot change the code , secondly the modal effect from left to right.